# Installing pypsignifit and importing it on jupiter notebook with VS code

Tags: gcc, makefile

I am trying to install pypsignifit (used for psychometric curve fitting) and I have been following their tutorial here: https://psignifit.sourceforge.net/INSTALL_MAC.html

I have gcc, I downloaded the zip file from https://sourceforge.net/projects/psignifit/

I did what the tutorial instructs: decompressed the file, went in its directory and ran `make install`

I have an error, which obviously results in the import not working
Here is the error message:

```
swignifit/swignifit_raw.cxx:22:82: warning: delete called on non-final 'MCMCList' that has virtual functions but non-virtual destructor [-Wdelete-non-abstract-non-virtual-dtor]
    SwigMovePointer& operator=(SwigMovePointer& rhs) { T* oldptr = ptr; ptr = 0; delete oldptr; ptr = rhs.ptr; rhs.ptr = 0; return *this; }
                                                                                 ^
swignifit/swignifit_raw.cxx:28:84: note: in instantiation of member function 'SwigValueWrapper<MCMCList>::SwigMovePointer::operator=' requested here
  SwigValueWrapper& operator=(const T& t) { SwigMovePointer tmp(new T(t)); pointer = tmp; return *this; }
                                                                                   ^
swignifit/swignifit_raw.cxx:28392:14: note: in instantiation of member function 'SwigValueWrapper<MCMCList>::operator=' requested here
      result = (arg1)->sample(arg2);
             ^
64 warnings and 11 errors generated.
error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
make: *** [python-install] Error 1
```

Since it mentions an error with gcc and I installed in a venv, I checked if it's somehow not installed, but it is:

```
 ~/MA/MI/H/psignifit_3.0_beta.20120611.1  which gcc                                                                                                                   2 err | 5s | HighSpeedRotationExperiment py | base py | 12:29:57 
/usr/bin/gcc
```

I tried installing without and with a venv, I made sure there in a make file in the zip. I also tried adding --user (it's not a thing for make install). Any suggestions?